# Helpful strategies to not getting lost in Large caves?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tips for not getting lost underground?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19817/tips-for-not-getting-lost-underground)

Once again I find myself lost in the passageways and caverns of a tunnel connected to a mine connected to a ravine connected to another mine.  I was thinking for a while I'll be fine until a creeper explodes in my face and destroys my breadcrumbs for returning home.

I'm hoping that someone has a good quick strategy to finding your way home even if you get turned around a bit after an explosion or falling through a hole.

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate on my phone in rome so cant look them up thx for the link i voted to delete the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

keep some non natural material on hand (planks) and mark where you came from in a arrow like config

```
p
 p
p
```

or consitently keep putting torches on one side of the cave as you go deeper

Answer (score 0):

Take a compass with you!
Other than that, putting torches only on your right side of the walls helped me out pretty much everytime.

Answer (score 0):

My usual strategy consists of me cuttig a path one block deep and widw through the tunnels and replacing it with cobblestone then placing torches in the direction of the exit.

This usually works till my curiousty and greed/boredom get the bette of me and i charge into the darkness in search of treasure. At this point i try to leave torches in a way to lead me out but it never seems to work.